# Do we need livedata if doing simple operation in viewmodel

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

So I am trying to write a simple app with just the viewModel and view for now. In that there is a simple date calculation. Should I use the livedata?

The data calculation is triggered by a method in the view and I calculate the final date and set it to the textview. There is no complex operation. Should I use a livedata and listen to it from the MainActivity or just return immediately from the method in viewmodel as I'm doing now. Which is the better way?

MainActivity.java

```java
@Override
    public void onMediaFocused(@NonNull MediaTypeUtil.MediaType mediaType, Uri uri) {
        dateTextView.setText(mMediaPlayerControlViewModel.getCreationDate(uri));

        }
    }
```

ViewHolder.java

```java
 private static final String PLAYER_DATE_FORMAT = "MMMM dd hh:mm a";
    private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

    public String getCreationDate(Uri uri) {
        try {
            File file = new File(uri.getPath());
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(PLAYER_DATE_FORMAT);
            BasicFileAttributes basicFileAttributes =
                    Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
            return df.format(basicFileAttributes.creationTime().toMillis());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return EMPTY_STRING;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use LiveData for two main reasons, so ask yourself:

1. Does my data need to be lifecycle aware and inherently retained?
2. Do I want to observe changes to my data and update things accordingly?

If these things are not integral to your use case then I wouldn't bother using LiveData to wrap data that isn't "live".